# Bring td to the top of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How can I bring a td to the top of a table? I have something like this:

```
    <table>
    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="pp" class="text-right"><!-- I want this td in the top of table when a is clicked-->
        <a ...>
        <i class=""></i>
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr><td>...</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move Rows up and down in html table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321320/move-rows-up-and-down-in-html-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the entire tr to the top. You can find the `closest` tr relative to the link, then `prepend` it to your table:

```
$("#pp a").on('click', function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.prependTo(tr.closest('table'))
});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreortigao/8kg9q9h0/)

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use jQuery's [`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to move the desired `<tr>` (row) to the top of the table.
Note that:

> If a single element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned).
>
> If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target except for the last one.

In my example, I use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse from the clicked `<td>` to its containing `<tr>` so that the entire row can be moved.

```js
jQuery('#pp').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('tr').prependTo('table');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>...</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="pp"><a><i class="">click to move this row to the top</i></a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>...</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work with my code, I use bootstrap and the table class name is 'table-condensed' I generate the the table content , something like this:  <tr>
                <td>{{product.code}}</td>
                <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                <td>{{product.typeString}}</td>
                <td>{{product.node?product.node.name}}</td>
                <td id="pp" class="text-right">
                    {% if request is defined %}
                        <a>...</a>

Comment: @dimvcl Please use the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33620961/edit) to update the code in your question. If possible, create a working example of your code so we can reproduce the problem.