# jQuery: change the order of two rows of a table

Tags: jquery

I want to change the order of two rows in a table.

I have this code:

```
console.log(position.parent().parent().prev());
console.log(position.parent().parent());
//I expected this line do the work, but no...
$(this).parent().parent().prev().insertAfter($(this).parent().parent());
```

That is printing this:

```
<tr>​
<td>​Element 1​</td>​
<td>​…​</td>​
<td>​2008-02-02​</td>​
<td class=​"jander" data-pos=​"0" data-category=​"1">​…​</td>​
</tr>​

<tr>​
<td>​Element 2​</td>​
<td>​…​</td>​
<td>​2007-02-02​</td>​
<td class=​"jander" data-pos=​"1" data-category=​"1">​…​</td>​
</tr>​
```

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');

row.insertAfter( row.next() );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hkkKs/

Depends on which one you're targeting. If the first one has the click handler, then you'd need the code above.

Also, the [`closest()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method is a safer way to target the ancestor `<tr>`. That may have been the issue.

If you want it the opposite way, your code would work, but again, use `.closest()` instead.

```
$('span').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    row.prev().insertAfter(row);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hkkKs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("tableSelector").append($("tableSelector").find("tr:first"));
```