# Reorder table rows using jquery

Tags: jquery

This table is in a template, I cannot directly edit the HTML and need the links to be in a different order, I need to move the "about" link below the "donate" link.

```
<table class="leftnav">

<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="headergraphica">
<img src=".../images/ta.gif">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="leftlinkheading">Information</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="leftlink"><a href="#">event information</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="leftlink"><a href="#">about</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="leftlink"><a href="#">participate</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="leftlink"><a href="#">donate</a></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sounds great, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this -

```
$('.leftlink a:contains("donate")').closest('tr')
           .after($('.leftlink a:contains("about")').closest('tr'));
```

Demo `----->`  http://jsfiddle.net/zCZfT/

Answer (score 0):

See some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617274/swapping-rows-in-jquery)

Could probably do

```
$(".leftnav tr:eq(3)").appendTo(".leftnav tbody");
```