# Is it wise to add variables to jQuery $ scope or is it polluting it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, jquery-selectors

I've just seen [some dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/617289/1525840) suggest the following syntax instead of the one I'm usually (always) using.

```
$newToMe = "I haven't used this way";
var oldWay = "I've always use this way";
```

The general quality of his answer to the original question suggests that he knows stuff and isn't just horsing around. Still, it seems to me like there's a risk of polluting the scope of jQuery by doing so.

Am I right to be cautious or is it a good way of keeping my own stuff in a narrow scope? Should one combine the scopiness and precautiously use something like the following?

```
$myCoolStuff.thing1 = $(".ones");
$myCoolStuff.thing2 = $(".twos");
```

Comment: Check out this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign

Comment: `$newToMe = "I haven't used this way";` that is not setting anything on the jQuery global object. That is simply making a variable named `$newToMe`. To have set something on the jQuery object one would have to do something like: `$.newToMe=""` or `jQuery.newToMe`

Comment: Another regarding same subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209462/when-why-to-prefix-variables-with-when-using-jquery?lq=1

Comment: @PatrickEvans You're perfectly right. I guess it's been so rooted in a programmers' minds that once we see a dollar, we see jQuery. Even if it's not there, which becomes obvious once some savvy answer points that out, like yours did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of "jQuery scope pollutions", the two alternatives are the same. `$me` is just one of (of many) conventions as to how to name a variable - this one being related to distinguishing jQuery objects from regular ones.

However, worth mentioning is that (given the code above) `$newToMe` will be added to the global scope (and found in `window`) where-as `oldWay` won't. Why? Well, the `var` keyword will cause it to be restricted to its current context.

Comment: Oh, I got mislead by the response being in the context of jQuery. But of course, for it to be  jQuery object we need to dottify in the name (*$.beep*). Otherwise it's going into *window.beep* or, rather,  *window.$beep*, just as you say.

Comment: _"where-as `oldWay` won't"_ only if done inside a function/closure, if done outside them it will be on the global object